# begin array but was string GSON

Tags: rest, exception, gson

I have a Web Service REST :

```
@Path("/Vehicles")    
public class Vehicles{
        @GET
        @Path("/Cars")
        @Produces(aplicattion/json)
        public String Cars() {

            Car[] cars = Consulting my database...

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            return gson.toJson(cars); 
        }
```

I consume the web service:

```
  try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                    "http://localhost:8080/Concessionaire/rest/Vehicles/Cars");

            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(get);

            String respGET = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Cars[] c = gson.fromJson(respGET,Cars[].class);

   }catch(Exception e){

   }
```

But appears this exception: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was String at line 1 colum 6
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns a String

```
public String Cars()
```

The client code expects a Car array

```
Cars[] c = gson.fromJson(respGET,Cars[].class);
```

Gson expects the BEGIN_ARRAY event while parsing the json but instead finds a String. To fix it, send a Cars[] using the jersey `Response` class and change the return type to `Response`.

```
return Response.ok(myCarsArray).build();
```